# Having a problem lining up my elements with CSS

Tags: css

I have an unordered list that contains links. Some of the links are text and some are text with icons. But I have a problem in that I can't get them to line up. Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong here. I have tried different combinations but still can't get things to line up.

Here is my HTML code. Note that I used an icon from another site. I can't link to my own site as its internal.

```
<div id="ftr_top_ctr" class="btn_lnk">
  <ul class="left">
    <li><a class="disabled" id="doCheckMark"   rel="nofollow">Mark</a></li>
    <li><a href="/aa" ><img class='ico' src="http://michaelwright.me/images/test.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="/aa" ><img class='ico' src="http://michaelwright.me/images/test.png" />Test</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>


div#ftr_top {
    height: 30px;
}
.btn_lnk ul.left {
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}
.btn_lnk ul {
    margin: 0;
}
.btn_lnk {
    font-size: 12px;
}
.btn_lnk ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#ftr_top_ctr a {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    padding: 3px 4px;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

You can see the code and what it displays: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86ZEf/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` to the `img`s.

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/86ZEf/4/

This problem was happening because the default `vertical-align` is `baseline`, [see here](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Add `float:left;` to `#ftr_top_ctr a` and give it a `line-height:16px;`. Add a rule for the icon: `#ftr_top_ctr a img {float:left;}`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9B2GA/).

Comment: Your jsFiddle link needs to be updated; at the moment, it's pointing to the one in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/86ZEf/8/

Instead of adding a border to the a elements, add it to the li elements and set a height on the li elements too. Lastly, remove the "float", set "li" to inline and you're good to go. Relevant snippet:

```
.btn_lnk ul li {
    display: inline;
    height: 22px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    padding: 3px 4px;
}
```

Here is the updated css in its entirity:

```
.btn_lnk ul.left {
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}
.btn_lnk ul {
    margin: 0;
}
.btn_lnk {
    font-size: 12px;
}
.btn_lnk ul li {
    display: inline;
    height: 22px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    padding: 3px 4px;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

img {
    vertical-align: top
}
```

Comment: You should check your demo in a WebKit browser.

Comment: chrome and safari both work fine - but I posted the wrong demo link, my apologies. I updated the answer with the correct link