# why is the a tag lower then the spans in IE

Tags: html, css

Here is my [page](http://posnation.com/pos_software)

**HTML**

```
<div class="pp-foot">
  <span class="big-call-btn"></span>
  <span class="big-chat-btn"></span>
  <a href="#contact_form_photo" rel="prettyPhoto[inline]" class="footer_btn_email_new  big-email-btn"><span></span></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pp-foot {
    background: url("../images/prod-page-foot.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top #E4E4E4;
    height: 77px;
}

.big-chat-btn {
   background: url("../images/product-chat-btn.png") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
   margin: 0 0 0 11px;
}

.pp-foot a {
    margin: 0 0 0 11px;
}
.big-email-btn {
    background: url("../images/product-email-btn.png") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
}
.big-call-btn, .big-chat-btn, .big-email-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 72px;
    width: 230px;
}
```

Any ideas what is causing the issue. Firefox is fine but IE is not

Comment: Don't get it. Looks the same in FF and IE. Exactly where in your page the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `vertical-align: top`.

```
.big-call-btn, .big-chat-btn, .big-email-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 72px;
    width: 230px;
}
```

More info:

- http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/
- http://www.brunildo.org/test/inline-block.html

Comment: [It](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142539/having-a-problem-lining-up-my-elements-with-css/7142553#7142553) is [always](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144843/extra-space-under-textarea-differs-along-browsers/7144960#7144960) `vertical-align`..